# What is the logic of debugging an out of range array with the remainder operator? How does the % keep it from going out of range?

Tags: arrays, swift, debugging

**Homework Problem:**
When the program tried to encrypt the "y" in ["c", "o", "d", "e", "c", "a", "d", "e", "m", "y"], it found its index in the alphabet, 24.

But when it looked up the letter 3 spaces to the right, which would be alphabet[27], it threw an error because the alphabet only has 26 elements! It is “out of range”.

To fix this, we can “wrap around” the alphabet by using the remainder operator: %.

On the line where we replace the current character in message, change alphabet[j+3] to alphabet[(j+3) % 26].

Now the new letter position will never go beyond 26.

**Code:**

```swift
var alphabet: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

var secretMessage = "codecademy"

var message = Array(secretMessage)


for h in 0..<message.count{

  for a in 0..<alphabet.count{

    if message[h] == alphabet[a]{

      message[h] = alphabet[(a+3)%26]

      break

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: message[h] = alphabet[(a+3)%26] - since a+3 will assign the element plus 3 indexes to the right for all of the other letters, until the index is out of range (for an example y) - is the "%26" part being used for every instance? if not - why? if so, how?

Comment: You probably need to research what a modulus operator does, then it should become clear.

Comment: I did - I know it provides a remainder. I guess I just need a little more guidance.

Comment: Why not write a separate piece of code where you loop from 0 to 26 and print the result of `(number + 3) % 26`, is the result what you expected? I would calculate the new index separately and check if it is too large and then adjust, basic but simple. An “ugly” hack is to add a, b and c to the end of your alphabet array…

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to know that `%` here means `modulo` in mathematics.

> In computing, the modulo operation returns the remainder or signed remainder of a division, after one number is divided by another (called the modulus of the operation).

Example: `5 % 2 = 1` ( because remainder of `5 mod 2 = 1`)

In here you use `% 26` which means it will never go beyond 26 in always get the remainder which is always < 26. Beside of that your array has only 26 values which at index `0->25`.

Combine both of them, that's the reason your problem which `out of range` is solved.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a thoughtful answer. Just to clarify - %26 in alphabet[(a+3)%26] isn't actually dividing/getting the remainder of anything but more so just saying it can't go beyond 26 elements? Also - in the problem above where we are using y + 3 , does it automatically know to restart the count from the beginning after hitting z?

Comment: Dear @KimberlyZelaya, it is getting the remainder of ``a + 3`` when mod to ``26``. Example for your question you have ``a = 25`` and ``[(a + 3)%26] = [(25 + 3)%26] = [28%26] = [2]`` so it will get value at index 2 of array which is ``"c"``. It is restricted can go beyond 26 because of the ``modulo``